# Can't access TP-Link TL-MR3220 ssh/telnet

Tags: ssh, telnet, router

I am unable to connect to my TP-Link TL-MR3220 router through SSH/Telnet. I have forwarded the ports 22 and 23 and try with Microsoft Telnet and PuTTY but it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL-MR3220 doesn't have SSH/Telnet enabled and it is blocked in the kernel with the default firmware.

However, if you flash the Router with a Third party firmware then you can access this via SSH or Telnet.

Here is a guide to install OpenWRT on the MR3220.
https://gist.github.com/sepastian/6712039